# summarise dplyr with dynamic columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I've some R-code which does, what I want it to do. But now the question: 
Is there any mechanism to avoid coding A1 A2 A3 and so on? I would like to code A* for all columns beginning with A. There can be any number of "A" columns in dependency to a list length which is definied in the code. The rest of the code is dynamic, but here I have a manual intervention (add some A columns or delete some A columns within the summerise statement).

I have found summarize_at, but I don't see how I can do the other things like last() and sum() at the same time for the other columns.

```
  l_af <- l_cf %>%
    group_by(PID, Server) %>%
    summarise(Player=last(Player),
              Guild=last(Guild),
              Points=last(Points),
              Battles=last(Battles),
              A1=max(A1),
              A2=max(A2),
              A3=max(A3),
              A4=max(A4),
              A5=max(A5),
              A6=max(A6),
              RecCount=sum(RecCount))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `summarise` it is removes all other columns if they are not used. You can consider to use `mutate` first perform all the operations and then use `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)

l_cf %>%
  group_by(PID, Server) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Player,Guild,Points,Battles), last) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("A")), max) %>%
  mutate(RecCount  = sum(RecCount)) %>%
  summarise_all(max)
```

A reproducible example

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, 2), x = runif(10), y = runif(10), 
                 a1 = runif(10), a2 = runif(10), z = runif(10))
```

First applying functions individually for each column

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(x=last(x),
            y=last(y),
            a1=max(a1),
            a2=max(a2),
            z=sum(z))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  group      x      y    a1    a2     z
#  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 0.0456 0.900  0.890 0.963 0.282
#2     2 0.528  0.246  0.693 0.902 0.648
#3     3 0.892  0.0421 0.641 0.691 0.880
#4     4 0.551  0.328  0.994 0.795 0.635
#5     5 0.457  0.955  0.656 0.232 1.01
```

Now apply the functions together for multiple columns

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x, y), last) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("a")), max) %>%
  mutate(z = sum(z)) %>%
  summarise_all(max)


#  group      x      y    a1    a2     z
#  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 0.0456 0.900  0.890 0.963 0.282
#2     2 0.528  0.246  0.693 0.902 0.648
#3     3 0.892  0.0421 0.641 0.691 0.880
#4     4 0.551  0.328  0.994 0.795 0.635
#5     5 0.457  0.955  0.656 0.232 1.01
```

We can see that both the approaches gave the same output.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my problem.

Btw. in my example "Guild" contains TRUE or FALSE values
After the mutate I got 1 or 0. I had to recode them, but It works.